# syntax error near 'CONSTRAINT

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE `DELIVERY` (
  `del_ID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `del_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `del_time` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `VEHICLE_veh_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  `DRIVER_dr_ID` INT NOT NULL,
  INDEX `fk_VEHICLE_has_DRIVER_DRIVER1_idx` (`DRIVER_dr_ID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_VEHICLE_has_DRIVER_VEHICLE1_idx` (`VEHICLE_veh_ID` ASC),
  PRIMARY KEY (`del_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_VEHICLE_has_DRIVER_VEHICLE1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`VEHICLE_veh_ID`)
    REFERENCES `ZionDB`.`VEHICLE` (`veh_ID`)
  CONSTRAINT `fk_VEHICLE_has_DRIVER_DRIVER1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`DRIVER_dr_ID`)
    REFERENCES `ZionDB`.`DRIVER` (`dr_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONSTRAINT `fk_VEHICLE_has_DRIVER_DRIVER1`
>       FOREIGN KEY (`DRIVER_dr_ID`)
>       ' at line 13

I need a hand with this as i don't understand my error and i'm stuck.

Comment: You are missing a comma after (`veh_ID`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget comma after first FK definition.

Correct syntax is

```
CREATE TABLE `DELIVERY` (
    `del_ID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `del_date` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `del_time` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `VEHICLE_veh_ID` INT NOT NULL,
    `DRIVER_dr_ID` INT NOT NULL,
    INDEX `fk_VEHICLE_has_DRIVER_DRIVER1_idx` (`DRIVER_dr_ID` ASC),
    INDEX `fk_VEHICLE_has_DRIVER_VEHICLE1_idx` (`VEHICLE_veh_ID` ASC),
    PRIMARY KEY (`del_ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_VEHICLE_has_DRIVER_VEHICLE1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`VEHICLE_veh_ID`)
        REFERENCES `ZionDB`.`VEHICLE` (`veh_ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_VEHICLE_has_DRIVER_DRIVER1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`DRIVER_dr_ID`)
        REFERENCES `ZionDB`.`DRIVER` (`dr_ID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```